# Why is my React app not running despite using yarnpkg and GitHub integration?

Tags: java, reactjs, github, yarnpkg

Am unable to run my project
warning ........\package.json: License should be a valid SPDX license expression
error functions@: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "18". Got "19.8.1"
error Commands cannot run with an incompatible environment.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 0):

Your local node version is different than what you mentioned in package.json.

Either change your node version using tools like `nvm` or change the required node version.